# Route53 wildcard domain - cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I need to create a CNAME for my ALB.

```
A  example.com alb-21212122.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I need to add a wildcard domain in route53.

```
ResourceRecrStat:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !ImportValue ZoneIdExample
      Name: "*.example.com."
      Type: CNAME
      TTL: '60'
      ResourceRecords:
        - example.com.
```

But cloudformation failed, resource cannot be created. I don't have any other records in route53.
it has only A record pointing to the load-balancer.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: it says The following resource(s) failed to update: [ResourceRecrStat]. can i point *.example.com to alb-21212122.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com, when creating the load-balancer. then i don't want to add a wildcard.

Comment: So where do you have `alb-21212122.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com` in the record?

Comment: A  example.com alb-21212122.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com, this is in route 53, this was added when creating the ALB.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Records Types are Different from typical uses.
They are known as alias records. Similar to CNAME records, alias records let you route traffic to selected AWS resources including ALB.
So you should use **Type: A** instead of CNAME
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html

The final Records format should be

Record name / Type / Alias / Value/ Route traffic to

example.com / A / Yes / alb-21212122.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com